# Send multiple parameters to SQL Server using dbBind in R

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, rodbc, r-dbi

I am working on a program that has to send data to Microsoft SQL Server through R. Since SQL Server doesn't have any *INSERT OR IGNORE INTO* like PostgreSQL, I have to check if the value is already in the table. However, I don't know if I'm doing it right. How do I send multiple parameters (or the same parameter twice) into SQL Server using dbBind?

Here is my code:

```
statement <- "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.nodes WHERE node_id=?) INSERT INTO dbo.nodes (node_id) VALUES (?)"     
insertnew <- dbSendQuery(conn, statement)    
test_p1 <- list(5, 6)    
test_p2 <- list(test_p1, test_p1)    
dbBind(insertnew, params=test_p2)
```

When I run it it gives me the following error:
**Error in result_bind(res@ptr, params, batch_rows) :
RAW() can only be applied to a 'raw', not a 'double'**

Using RStudio's Show Traceback feature, it shows this:
`result_bind(res@ptr, params, batch_rows)`
`.local(res, params, ...)`
`dbBind(insertnew, params = test_p1)`

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? If the parameters should be something other than a list of lists, what should they be? Is there a way to name parameters to use twice in the same statement? What is *RAW()* and what is it trying to apply it to?

*dbo.nodes* is a table with one column, `node_id NVARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY`.
`conn` is a *DBIConnection* object created earlier using `dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), ...)`. It works for executing other statements so there shouldn't be a problem there.
Adding the argument `batch_rows=1` to *dbBind* doesn't change anything (not that I understand what that is supposed to do).

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Or if anyone knows any documentation you can link me to, or an example showing how this is done, that would be great as well

Answer (score 0):

```
test_p1 = c(5, 6)
test_p2 = unname(data.frame(I(test_p1), I(test_p1)))
```

In case this helps someone looking this up later, changing it from a list of lists to a data frame made from vectors worked.